# plugin to post from admin to flickr

Tags: posts, admin, plugin-recommendation, wp-admin, gallery

I'm looking for a plgin which allows the admins to post to flickr directly from the admin panel when posting.
I saw this and thought it would work but seems to only 'get' images not 'post' them

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-flickr-press/

and the documentation is a bit patchy & japanese

Answer (score 0):

You may find [Wordpress Flickr Manager](http://trentgardner.net/wordpress-flickr-manager/) useful.

Comment: This seems not to be available anymore...